# Is it possible to pass a custom comparator to lodash's sortBy function?

Tags: javascript, lodash

For example, I want to sort with respect to `Intl.Collator().compare`. Is there any way to pass this comparator to be used by `_.sortBy`?

Comment: What are the items that are being sorted?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the [native `sort` method?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=example)

Comment: The items that are being sorted are objects with a name string field that may contain foreign language characters.
---
Currently I am using the native `sort` doing something like `arr.slice.sort((a, b) => Intl.Collator().compare(a.name, b.name))`, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way.

Comment: @MikeC If you are using `_.chain` and wan't to sort somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 6):

You can use lodash mixin's

```
_.mixin({
    sortWith : function(arr, customFn) {
        return _.map(arr).sort(customFn)
    }
});
```

You can now do

```
_.sortWith(array, function(a, b) {
   //custom function that returns either -1, 0, or 1 if a is <, ==, or > than b
});
```

You can now chain this like:

```
_.chain(myObject)
    .get('some_array_property')
    .sortWith(function(a, b) {
        //determine if a <=> b 
     })
    .value();
```

Internally, sortWith maps the array to a new array so that it doesn't modify the array passed into it and uses the [native sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=example) method.

Answer (score 4):

No, unfortunately this is **not** currently possible.

A workaround is to use the `iteratees` function to map the values to something the standard comparator will sort correctly. This is however almost never practical.

It's also asked for here https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/246, but no response from the author.

Answer (score 4):

This is enough for simple ordering based on finite values.

```
const MAP = {
    BRONZE: 1,
    SILVER: 2,
    GOLD: 3,
    PLATINUM: 4,
}

const DATA = [
    { name: 'A', type: 'SILVER' },
    { name: 'B', type: 'BRONZE' },
    { name: 'C', type: 'PLATINUM' },
    { name: 'F', type: 'SILVER' },
    { name: 'G', type: 'GOLD' },
    { name: 'H', type: 'BRONZE' },
]

_.sortBy(DATA, (item) => MAP[item.type])
```

Result:

```
[
    {"name":"B","type":"BRONZE"},
    {"name":"H","type":"BRONZE"},
    {"name":"A","type":"SILVER"},
    {"name":"F","type":"SILVER"},
    {"name":"G","type":"GOLD"},
    {"name":"C","type":"PLATINUM"}
]
```

Comment: is this a new feature? was this added in recent times? Because ```sortBy``` is already mentioned in the question but without the feature you used.
If so please specify in the answer from which version of ```lodash``` this is available to complete your answer.

Comment: Looks like it was already in earlier versions.

[Lodash 1.3.1](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/1.3.1/doc/README.md#_sortbycollection--callbackidentity-thisarg)

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you are looking for. But if you are finding ways to use comparator in lodash sort, this may help:

Using `_.chain()` to get lodash collect will enable you to pass in comparator to `sort()`

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(_.sortBy(res, lat))); // sortBy doesn't take in comparator

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    _.chain(res)
      .sort((a, b) => b.lat - a.lat) // sort takes in comparator
      .value()
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not lodash, but might come in handy for someone looking for native sort.

```js
var customSort = (
  selector,
  options,
  locales = undefined,
) => (a, b) => {
  return selector(a).localeCompare(selector(b), locales, {numeric: true,...options});
};

var x = [
  { name: '1-test' },
  { name: '01-test' },
  { name: '11-test' },
  { name: '11-Test' },
  { name: '10-test' },
  { name: '40-btest' },
  { name: '40-ctest' },
  { name: '40-atest' },
  { name: '2-test' },
  { name: '20-test' },
  { name: 'ätest' },
  { name: 'atest' },
];

console.log(x.sort(customSort((x) => x.name)));
console.log(x.sort(customSort((x) => x.name, { caseFirst: 'upper' })));
// in Swedish
console.log(x.sort(customSort((x) => x.name, { sensitivity: 'base' },'sv')));
```

Options come from:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Answer (score 1):

As said by other answers, you cannot pass in a comparator to `_.sortBy` like in `Array.prototype.sort()`.

One workaround would be to add a new calculated property to the objects which would be the ordering and then use `_.sortBy` on that.

So if you had a list of objects like `[{name: "hello there"}, {name: "world"}]` but you wanted to sort them by name length, you could do:

```
_(arr)
//augment each object with a calculated `order` property
.map(obj => ({...obj, order: obj.name.length}))
.sortBy('order')
.value()
```

Result: `[{name: "world", order: 5}, {name: "hello there", order: 11}]`

Answer (score 1):

Simple implementaion for `lodash/fp` (functional programming lodash) with currying (not restricted to lodash actually):

```
const sortWith = comparator => list => list.map(i => i).sort(comparator);
```

And for TypeScript:

```js
type ComparatorFn<T> = (a: T, b: T) => number;

const sortWith = <P>(comparator: ComparatorFn<P>) => (list: P[]): P[] => list.map(i => i).sort(comparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the corresponding issue, here is stated that the mentioned feature is already merged long ago but unfortunately not released yet. https://github.com/lodash/lodash/pull/3764. This would be really great to have it available

Answer (score 1):

actually iteratees can be mapping for the return result:

```
const users = [
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40 },
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 }
];

_.sortBy(users, [function(o) { return o.user; }]);
// output: objects for [['barney', 36], ['barney', 34], ['fred', 48], ['fred', 40]]
```

or iteratees can be normal js sort function like i made in the below example to sort array of objects to sort cards when `cardsStatus === 'NORI'` so card should be on top of array

```
const cardsBeforeSort = [
              {
                "cardStatus": "NORM",
                "consumedLimit": 0,
                "cardAccountSerial": "10551880",
                "cashLimit": null,
                "applePayStatus": "ELIGIBLE",
                "embossName": "Hdhh",
                "nickName": "",
                "aan": "123",
                "balance": -9,
                "key": "405433******8106"
              },
              {
                "cardStatus": "NORI",
                "consumedLimit": 0,
                "cardAccountSerial": "10551908",
                "cashLimit": null,
                "applePayStatus": "ELIGIBLE",
                "embossName": "Hdhh",
                "nickName": "",
                "aan": "123",
                "balance": 1,
                "key": "405433******8382"
              },
              {
                "cardStatus": "HOLD",
                "consumedLimit": -169122.81,
                "cardAccountSerial": "10548192",
                "cashLimit": null,
                "applePayStatus": "ELIGIBLE",
                "embossName": "Hdjj",
                "nickName": "",
                "aan": "123",
                "balance": 5579.29,
                "key": "417323******3321"
              },
              {
                "cardStatus": "NORI",
                "consumedLimit": -7.74,
                "cardAccountSerial": "10549814",
                "cashLimit": null,
                "applePayStatus": "ELIGIBLE",
                "embossName": "Hdhh",
                "nickName": "",
                "aan": "123",
                "balance": 1,
                "key": "429927******1548"
              }
            ]
    
       const sortedCards = sortBy(userCards, [
          (first, second) =>
            first.cardStatus === 'NORI' ? -1 : second === 'NORI' ? 1 : 0,
        ]);
```

this will result in the following output:

```
console.log(sortedCards);
    [
          {
            "cardStatus": "NORI",
            "consumedLimit": -7.74,
            "cardAccountSerial": "10549814",
            "cashLimit": null,
            "applePayStatus": "ELIGIBLE",
            "embossName": "Hdhh",
            "nickName": "",
            "aan": "123",
            "balance": 1,
            "key": "429927******1548"
          },
          {
            "cardStatus": "NORI",
            "consumedLimit": 0,
            "cardAccountSerial": "10551908",
            "cashLimit": null,
            "applePayStatus": "ELIGIBLE",
            "embossName": "Hdhh",
            "nickName": "",
            "aan": "123",
            "balance": 1,
            "key": "405433******8382"
          },
          {
            "cardStatus": "NORM",
            "consumedLimit": 0,
            "cardAccountSerial": "10551880",
            "cashLimit": null,
            "applePayStatus": "ELIGIBLE",
            "embossName": "Hdhh",
            "nickName": "",
            "aan": "123",
            "balance": -9,
            "key": "405433******8106"
          },
          {
            "cardStatus": "HOLD",
            "consumedLimit": -169122.81,
            "cardAccountSerial": "10548192",
            "cashLimit": null,
            "applePayStatus": "ELIGIBLE",
            "embossName": "Hdjj",
            "nickName": "",
            "aan": "123",
            "balance": 5579.29,
            "key": "417323******3321"
          },
        ]
```

actually the benefit of using sortBy lodash function is being **functional programming immutable solution** because of not mutating **cardsBeforeSort** array